# How to change the order of the posts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use the

> Post.order(:created_at)

in the controller and the posts are ordered by create time, but it come out from the oldest to the newest post, that is what i don't want, I want to change the order to display the recent posts first, how can I change the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Post.order("created_at desc")`

Tip: Use a `scope` so this logic remains on your model, not on your controller.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
  scope :recent_first, order("created_at desc")
end
```

Then, on your controller, you can just use `Post.recent_first`.